# Trying to export data to csv file from my firebase data gives undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, csv, react-hooks

I have a list of data from my firebase firestore that I want to export to .csv

I did everything that is required but when I add the values that I want to be exported they are always undefined.

I am not an expert in react I am somewhat intermediate but I think it is because I am setting my data inside a `useEffect Hook.`

My data `useState` is undefined, although it holds values and I can see them in my table, which is causing the CSVLink to throw errors.

How do I allow my data to be passed into the headers?

Here is my code:

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [id, setID] = useState("");
  const list = []
  const filteredList = []
  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.firestore().collection("Users").get().then((userSnapshot) => {

      userSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
       
        const {powerAccount,first_name,registerDate,email,company,country,phone} = doc.data();
        setID(doc.data().usersID)
        list.push({
          usersID:doc.id,
          powerAccount:powerAccount,
          first_name:first_name,
          registerDate:registerDate,
          email:email,
          company:company,
          country:country,
          phone:phone,
        });
      });
      setData(list);
    });
  },[]);


const headers = [
                  // here all the keys give undefined.
    {label:'User',key:data.usersID},
    {label:'Account',key:data.powerAccount},
    {label:'Name',key:data.first_name},
    {label:'RegistrationDate',key:data.registerDate},
    {label:'Email',key:data.email},
    {label:'Company',key:data.company},
    {label:'Country',key:data.country},
    {label:'Phone',key:data.phone},
  ];

 const csvReport = {
    filename:"userReport.csv",
    headers:headers,
    data: data // also my data useState is undefined, although it holds values and i can see them in my table
  }

    return (
     <CSVLink  {...csvReport} >
            Export
     </CSVLink>
    )
```

Comment: Fetching data from firebase is asynchronous so the data will be undefined as you're implementing right now.

Answer (score 1):

According to your implementation, fetching data from firebase is async so the `csvData` is getting undefined because it's not updating after a state update
Try changing your code like this and let me know if it works fine

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
  filename: "userReport.csv",
  headers: [],
  data: [],
});
const [id, setID] = useState("");
const filteredList = [];
useEffect(() => {
  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("Users")
    .get()
    .then((userSnapshot) => {
      let list = [];
      userSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const {
          powerAccount,
          first_name,
          registerDate,
          email,
          company,
          country,
          phone,
        } = doc.data();
        setID(doc.data().usersID);
        list.push({
          usersID: doc.id,
          powerAccount: powerAccount,
          first_name: first_name,
          registerDate: registerDate,
          email: email,
          company: company,
          country: country,
          phone: phone,
        });
      });
      const headers = [
        // I'm not sure why you need this key
        // but if it's only for uniqueness
        // you can replace them by unique strings like
        // { label: "User", key: "user" },
        // { label: "Account", key: "account" },

        { label: "User", key: data.usersID },
        { label: "Account", key: data.powerAccount },
        { label: "Name", key: data.first_name },
        { label: "RegistrationDate", key: data.registerDate },
        { label: "Email", key: data.email },
        { label: "Company", key: data.company },
        { label: "Country", key: data.country },
        { label: "Phone", key: data.phone },
      ];

      const csvReport = {
        filename: "userReport.csv",
        headers: headers,
        data: list,
      };
      setData(csvReport);
    });
}, []);

return <CSVLink {...data}>Export</CSVLink>;
```

Comment: i am getting data.map is not a function now when i use this code.

Comment: i need my data use state to be independent of the csv Report.

Answer (score 1):

You should all state coordination / update to `useState` and `useEffect` hooks and avoid relying on any field update outside the scope of these.

You should then remove the `list` variable, move state update to your effect hook and consolidate all users data in the same structure:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  firebase.firestore()
    .collection("Users")
    .get()
    .then((userSnapshot) => {
      const usersData = [];
      userSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const { powerAccount, first_name, registerDate, email, company, country, phone, userID } = doc.data();
        const userData = {
          usersID: doc.id,
          powerAccount: powerAccount,
          first_name: first_name,
          registerDate: registerDate,
          email: email,
          company: company,
          country: country,
          phone: phone,
        };
        const headers = [
          // here all the keys give undefined.
          { label: 'User', key: userID },
          { label: 'Account', key: powerAccount },
          { label: 'Name', key: first_name },
          { label: 'RegistrationDate', key: registerDate },
          { label: 'Email', key: email },
          { label: 'Company', key: company },
          { label: 'Country', key: country },
          { label: 'Phone', key: phone },
        ];
        const csvReport = {
          filename: "userReport.csv",
          headers: headers,
          data: userData
        }
        usersData.push(csvReport);
      });
      setData(usersData);
    });
}, []);

return (
  <CSVLink  {...data} >
    Export
  </CSVLink>
)
```

You may need add loading state to reflect the UI effect of data being loaded.

Comment: i am getting an error when trying this code reading " Data should be a "String", "Array of arrays" OR "Array of objects"  i believe it is because of the data:userData in the csvReport

Comment: i need my setData to be different from the csv report, here you are pushing csvReport which will cause no users to be fetched for me when i try to fetch my users into my table

Answer (score -1):

I think there are two things that causes the problem that you need to understand.

1. [Asynchronous Function](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/)
2. [React Lifecycle](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_asynchronous.asp)

Fetching data from firebase is asynchronous and might take sometime before you get the returned data while you have saved `csvReport` as constant variables and set it up as React element properties. So when firebase is still loading your data and your react component is already rendered / mounted, your `data` state has value of `[]` from default value as defined in the `useState` statement. Based on your code, your `csvReport` constant variable will not be receiving new data from firebase unless your app is re-rendered (enter new lifecycle and repeat). For example, switching to other tab component and go back to this component without refreshing the browser.

```
const csvReport = {
    filename:"userReport.csv",
    headers:headers, => [{ label: "User", key: undefined }, ...etc]; undefined bcs `data` is []
    data: data => the value is []
  }
```

So the simple solution is **NOT** to save the data as constant variable and set up the React element properties directly from your useState variable. Based on your code, I would make some changes like this.

```
...your previous code

const getHeaders = () => {
  // Do your data manipulation using `data` in useState
  // For example:
  const headers = data && data.map(item => {return {id: item.id}})
  return headers
}

return (
  <CSVLink
    filename="userReport.csv"
    headers={getHeaders()}
    data={data}
  >
     Export
  </CSVLink>
)
```

Hope this helps and have fun making changes :)

Comment: still doesnt work because data is undefined in the CSVLink